# Paypal IPN History is blank

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm sending preapproval calls to the API, these calls are successful and I am redirected back to the correct page but when I go to view the IPN History within my test business account it's blank, it's like there's no transaction taking place at all.

My IPN listener picks up nothing from these successful transactions BUT works just fine when I use the tester provided by PayPal.

I've been plugging away for a few days here and I'm not sure what else I can do to debug this. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If your IPN History in PayPal doesn't show anything then it's not POSTing anything.

According to the [Adaptive Payments IPN documentation](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIPN), the only IPN messages it sends are for payments and disputes.

If you need to save Preapproval profile details to your database, send email notifications, etc. you can do that from within the actual sign-up flow.  You can then use IPN to manage payments associated with that profile from there on.